# invalid syntax in views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, web-frameworks

The code was working. However, I got this error suddenly :

[image]

Even though the name of view and the name of function are same(in this case "addArticle"), I got this error. How can I fix that issue?

Here is what my **urls.py** contains :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views



app_name = "article"

urlpatterns = [
     path('dashboard/',views.dashboard,name = "dashboard"),
     path('addarticle/',views.addArticle,name = "addarticle"),]
```

Comment: Please add the error (full traceback) as text and please show the code where the error is reported. Wild guess: You have unbalanced parentheses in the previous line.

Comment: You forgot to close a bracket at the previous line. One can (slightly) see that at the top of the image. The "yellow" bracket is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a close bracket on line 22

Comment: OMG yes thank you so much!

Comment: You ré welcome.